# Subset data frame filling certain columns with NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset data and fill all rows in certain columns with NA values.  It is easier to follow with an example:

```
x[,c(1,3,NA,5,NA)]
```

to return this:

[image]

I know that this obviously won't work since i don't have these NA columns in x. But is there some way to do this? Perhaps paste two subsets together with NA columns between?

Comment: Just do `cbind(x[c(1,3)], NA, x[5], NA)`

Comment: ahh yes, still getting my feet under myself in R, thank you.

Comment: Also learn to use the `is.na<-` function, e.g.; `is.na(x[ , c(3,5)] <- TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @konvas, just use `cbind`.

Here's a worked example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(trait1 = 1:2, something = c("A", "B"), 
                   trait2 = 3:4, nothing = c("C", "D"), height = 5:6)
mydf
#   trait1 something trait2 nothing height
# 1      1         A      3       C      5
# 2      2         B      4       D      6
cbind(mydf[c(1, 3)], NA, mydf[5], NA)
#   trait1 trait2 NA height NA
# 1      1      3 NA      5 NA
# 2      2      4 NA      6 NA
```